# php twig template html code

Tags: php, twig

I have a problem relation with twig template.

```
final class index {

public $request;
private $loader;
private $twig;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * definition : class preloader with default
 * symfony component request class
 * twig template configuration
 * @param type dependency injection and function
 */
public function __construct(){

    //get request info
    $this->request=new request();
    $this->loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(root.'/src/declarations/twigTemplate');
    $this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($this->loader, array(
        //'cache' => root.'/src/declarations/twigTemplate/cache',

    ));
}

/**
 * get declaration main function.
 * definition:index method is defined in a declaration
 * and it is called as https://ip/company/service/app/service/doc
 * @param type dependency injection and function
 * @return array
 */
public function index(){

    //return
    return $this->twig->render("index.twig",['var'=>'foo']);

}
```

}

my twig file outputs as same html codes.namely,it doesn't run html codes.

index.twig file :

```
<strong>{{ var }}</strong>
```

output :

```
<strong>foo</strong>
```

I can solve this problem.already thanks for your answers

Comment: Did you change the `autoescaper` configuration?

Comment: I tried it, it does not work.

Comment: I posted an answer you said you could solve it already but most likely you read the twig documentation and found what i posted as an answer?

Comment: Could you post how you register/load `Twig`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use autoescape tags and/or Raw tags

```
{% autoescape %}
    {{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

So lets say this:

```
{% set example= "<h1>Test</h1>" %}
{{ example|raw }} <-- This will output Test in H1 
{{ example }} <-- This will output <h1>Test</h1>
```

I know you had already found an answer to your problem. but if others have this problem this are solutions to outputting HTML in twig. Hope this helps.

Comment: OP's `HTML` is not inside the variable as shown in OP's question, so `raw` and `autoescape` won't solve a thing

Comment: Ah yes I see. Sorry. Had an brainfart or something I read it as an twig syntax. The variable is in PHP. Oops.